# NSCondition, what if no lock when call signal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nscondition

From [this Apple's document about `NSCondition`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW18), the usage of `NSCondition` should be:

**Thead 1:**

```
[cocoaCondition lock];
while (timeToDoWork <= 0)
    [cocoaCondition wait];
timeToDoWork--;
// Do real work here.
[cocoaCondition unlock];
```

**Thread 2:**

```
[cocoaCondition lock];
timeToDoWork++;
[cocoaCondition signal];
[cocoaCondition unlock];
```

And in [the document of method `signal` in `NSConditon`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCondition/signal):

> You use this method to wake up one thread that is waiting on the condition. You may call this method multiple times to wake up multiple threads. If no threads are waiting on the condition, this method does nothing. **To avoid race conditions, you should invoke this method only while the receiver is locked**.

## My question is:

I don't want the *Thread 2* been blocked in any situation, so I removed the `lock` and `unlock` call in *Thread 2*. That is, *Thread 2* can put as many work as it wish, *Thread 1* will do the work one by one, if no more work, it wait (blocked). This is also a producer-consumer pattern, but the producer never been blocked.

But the way is not correct according to Apple's document So what things could possibly go wrong in this pattern? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failing to lock is a serious problem when multiple threads are accessing shared data. In the example from Apple's code, if Thread 2 doesn't lock the condition object then it can be incrementing `timeToDoWork` at the same time that Thread 1 is decrementing it. That can result in the results from one of those operations being lost. For example:

Thread 1 reads the current value of `timeToDoWork`, gets 1
Thread 2 reads the current value of `timeToDoWork`, gets 1
Thread 2 computes the incremented value (`timeToDoWork` + 1), gets 2
Thread 1 computes the decremented value (`timeToDoWork` - 1), gets 0
Thread 2 writes the new value of `timeToDoWork`, stores 2
Thread 1 writes the new value of `timeToDoWork`, stores 0

`timeToDoWork` started at 1, was incremented and decremented, so it should end at 1, but it actually ends at 0. By rearranging the steps, it could end up at 2, instead. Presumably, the value of `timeToDoWork` represents something real and important. Getting it wrong would probably screw up the program.

If your two threads are doing something as simple as incrementing and decrementing a number, they can do it without locks by using the atomic operation functions, such as `OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier()` and `OSAtomicDecrement32Barrier()`. However, if the shared data is any more complicated than that (and it probably is in any non-trivial case), then they really need to use synchronization mechanisms such as condition locks.

Comment: Thanks Ken. The actual situation I'm working on is a producer-cusumer pattern, I use the NSMutableArray to implement it. Where one thread add object to it, another thread take off objects. When no objects, the consumer thread wait. But I don't want the producer thread been blocked. Is there any way  to implement this?

Comment: You ***have to*** synchronize access to an `NSMutableArray`. It is not safe to mutate it while other threads might be accessing it. One mechanism you can use to synchronize that access is to put all accesses as tasks on a serial GCD queue. Pushes can be async. That would allow the producer to continue, using the GCD queue as a secondary, thread-safe data structure of sorts. However, what sense does it make for your producer to run ahead of your consumer indefinitely? You eventually need it to stop and wait for the consumer to catch up or you're going to consume memory and other resources.

Comment: Yes I get it, really appreciated. With respect to my situation, it is a message sender, the user can continuous tap or move on the screen to produce many many messages, and another thread - the consumer - to send the messages out. So the main thread (the producer) can't be blocked.

Comment: You can dispatch your producer onto an asynchronous serial queue. This can then block without impacting your UI